# Run a list of jUnit runners

Tags: junit, junit-runner

I have some test suites that in essence looks like

```
@Test
public void test1_2() {
    test(1,2);
}
@Test
public void test1_3() {
    test(1,3);
}
@Test
public void test4_5() {
    test(4,5);
}
@Test
public void test4_9() {
    test(4,9);
}

// and so forth

private void test(int i, int j) throws AssertionError{
    // ...
}
```

(This is not the actual tests, but the essence, each `@Test` method only calls one method)

So my thinking was that I could use `@RunWith` for a custom [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html) which accepts a `List` of [jUnit Runner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Runner.html)s.

How would this be achived? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use @Parameter ?

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class YourTest{

 private int i;
 private int j;

 public Parameter(int i, int j) {
    this.i= i;
    this.j= j;
 }

 @Parameters
 public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
      Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1, 2 }, { 1,3 }, { 4,5 }, { 4,9 } };
      return Arrays.asList(data);
 }

 @Test
 public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    //use i & j
 } 
}
```

Comment: yeah, that seems like a straight forward solution

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like something that should be done with [Theories](https://blogs.oracle.com/jacobc/entry/junit_theories). Otherwise, you could use [Enclosed](http://ghostganz.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/junit-hidden-feature-enclosed/) to have multiple inner classes each with its own runner.